# How do I pass a type through a function and use it to find all off that variable type?

Tags: c#, types, parameter-passing

For my C# Project, I have a base class (GameObject) and subclasses/child classes (Ball, Pin, Rope). In the code featured, im trying to search through the array of GameObjects to return a list based on the type needed which is passed through the function. I tried using a for loop to do:

_go[i] is type

where type is the type passed in, although getting an error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to GameObject

Where am I going wrong?

```
    public List<GameObject> ObjectsByType(Type type)
    {
        List<GameObject> gobytype;
        for(int i  = 0; i < _go.Count(); i++)
        {
            if(_go[i] is type)
            {
                //code here....
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type` is a class whose instances describe a type, and it's not the same thing as a type argument in a generic function, which is probably what you want here.

Here is a small complete example of a working solution:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class GameObject { }
class Ball : GameObject { }
class Rope : GameObject { }

class Program {

    static GameObject[] _go = new GameObject[] {
        new Ball(),
        new Rope()
    };

    static List<TGameObject> ObjectsByType<TGameObject>() where TGameObject : GameObject {
        List<TGameObject> gameObjects = new List<TGameObject>();
        foreach (var gameObject in _go) {
            TGameObject tobj = gameObject as TGameObject;
            if (tobj != null) {
                gameObjects.Add(tobj);
            }
        }
        return gameObjects;
    }

}
```

Also note that if you use LINQ you can do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

    static List<TGameObject> ObjectsByType<TGameObject>() where TGameObject : GameObject {
        return _go.OfType<TGameObject>().ToList();
    }
```

At that point, you pretty much don't need the function any more and you can just use `OfType`.

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helps you, you can vote it up (if your reputation allows you) and/or mark it as the accepted answer.